# How to remove "Fish Eye" effect on SceneKit camera?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, distortion, fieldofview

I'm using SceneKit. I have created and assigned my own camera to the scene and I have adjusted its xFov and yFov. When I set a value higher than 50, there starts to be some distortion. Everything near the edges of the screen is stretched – almost like the camera suddenly becomes a "Fish Eye."

I need the xFov and yFov to be above 50 (I actually need it to be 100), but I can't have that distortion. What do I do?

Comment: How do you propose a wide field of view fit in a narrow viewport without distortion?

Comment: @rickster Are you saying that it's theoretically impossible?

Comment: Using an orthographic projection would obviously remove this distortion, but I'm not sure that's what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking isn't theoretically impossible per se, but theoretically interesting at least.

What happens to a physical camera when you increase the field of view? The wider it gets, the more "fisheye" it looks. The projection matrix and perspective divide of a 3D graphics pipeline like SceneKit works in a similar way. It looks a little different because it's a rectilinear transformation rather than the effect of a spherical lens, but it's the same general idea — it maps a volume (called a frustum) of 3D space "seen" by the camera onto the viewing plane. This is a general aspect of 3D graphics, not something specific to SceneKit, so you can find plenty of [good tutorials](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) that cover the [underlying math](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) pretty well.

That frustum projection fixes a certain relationship between the amount of viewing angle something takes up and its width on the viewing plane. You can't really change that relationship and still have a linear (well, rational, but mostly linear) transformation that 3D hardware can apply with a single matrix multiplication (and perspective divide).

You could, in theory, define a different relationship — say, one where a large angular size corresponds to a much larger part of the viewing plane near the center of the view, but to a much smaller part farther away from the center. But you can't do that in the camera transform... You'd have to do such calculations pixel by pixel in  [some kind of post-processing shader](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNTechnique_Class/index.html). (In fact, this is generally how [rendering for the lenses of a VR headset](http://rifty-business.blogspot.com/2013/08/improving-on-distortion-shader.html?m=1) works.)